# Can MathJax be imported to a JS file used by a local HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

On the MathJax [homepage](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted), we find the code to import the [tex-mml-chtml](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/components/combined.html#tex-mml-chtml) configuration directly into an HTML document, without any need for a server. Attempting to modify the [example on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22viewport%22%20content%3D%22width%3Ddevice-width%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3EMathJax%20example%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fpolyfill.io%2Fv3%2Fpolyfill.min.js%3Ffeatures%3Des6%22%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20id%3D%22MathJax-script%22%20async%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.jsdelivr.net%2Fnpm%2Fmathjax%403%2Fes5%2Ftex-mml-chtml.js%22%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%0A%20%20When%20%5C(a%20%5Cne%200%5C)%2C%20there%20are%20two%20solutions%20to%20%5C(ax%5E2%20%2B%20bx%20%2B%20c%20%3D%200%5C)%20and%20they%20are%0A%20%20%5C%5Bx%20%3D%20%7B-b%20%5Cpm%20%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2-4ac%7D%20%5Cover%202a%7D.%5C%5D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&live) below the boilerplate slightly, I separated the import statement into JS and HTML files on my local machine:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax example</title>
  <script id="main"
          type="module"
          src="main.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
  When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
  \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import * as jax from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js";
```

---

I get the following errors:

[image: console errors]

and a warped output, although it does still make an attempt:

[image: warped output]

I am not sure if this outcome is because we simply *cannot* use MathJax in this manner (the proper manner being a call in the source HTML document, or via a server), or rather because I am missing some JS, or because I am calling the wrong configuration, etc.

If this is *not* possible, an explanation of why not (perhaps some CORS machinery? using JS modules incorrectly? MathJax simply not designed that way?) would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you’re missing the font(s).

Comment: @DaveNewton the link to the first font is verbatim `http://../es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2/MathJax_Zero.woff`, so the `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` makes sense. the other two are the same. i wonder why only these three resources fail?

Comment: This script https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js does not include any `export` statements. It's not an Ecmascript Module. You can try with https://esm.sh/mathjax@3.2.2.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, unfortunately that came up with another `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error in a new place for me, and reverted HTML to plain text (no MathJax interpretation at all)

Comment: Looks like there are still some `require()` calls in jsdelivr's Ecmascript Module version. You might want to try bundling the script with `bun`, `deno`, or an application that strictly bundles then use that script as a n Ecmascript Module.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation at https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html for installing your own copy?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger this results in the same errors as pictured in the original post (when importing from the same `tex-mml-chtml.js` file but locally rather than from CDN)

Comment: @guest271314 any resources to accomplish this would be appreciated! attempting to use an npm-installed copy via Peter's link (if that counts as bundling) leaves me with the same errors

Comment: @shea I'll look into it. I would bundle the CommonJS source code to an Ecmascript Module using `bun`, `deno`, `esbuild`, or `rollup`.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use the jsbin version locally?

Comment: @guest271314 (i used npm install version and assumed that it is 'basically' a bundled version for local use. this could definitely be wrong. no reason for preference.) to clarify, is jsbin version what is accessible through the esm link you attached before? i am unsure of the steps required to bundle from that point (`bun build` on the esm URL?)

Comment: `bun build ./index.js --target=browser --outfile=buffer.js` on the entry point, if there is one, e.g., https://gist.github.com/guest271314/08b19ba88c98a465dd09bcd8a04606f6. Here's the documentation for local usage https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html#config-loads-mathjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax sometimes needs to load additional resources that are not in the `tex-mml-chtml` file; in your case, it is the font files.  So it needs to know where to get them.  Normally, MathJax will look up the location where it was loaded using the `src` attribute of the `script` tag that loaded it.  In your case, however, since you are importing it into another file instead of loading it with its own `script` tag, MathJax can't figure out where it should look for the other resources.

In order to overcome that, you need to tell MathJax explicitly where you have placed its files.  You can do that by including

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {
    paths: {
      mathjax: 'url-for-the-mathjax-files'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*before* the script that loads MathJax itself (that is, before your `main.js` file is loaded).  You can, of course, put the `window.MathJax` declaration into a separate file and `import` that into your `main.js` file before the `import` of `tex-mml-chtml.js`.

As was mentioned in the comments, `tex-mml-chtml.js` does now have any exports, so you only need to do

```js
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js";
```

to load it.

Comment: i unzipped the [master](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/archive/master.zip) which becomes `MathJax-master`, and then copied the (full path to the) subdirectory `es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2` (and the files within it) into my local project directory, specifically into a new folder called `jax-files`. only alterations are using `mathjax: 'jax-files'` and a separate `loader.js` as recommended. thanks so much

Comment: ^ small addendum is `es5` portion of directory needs to be dropped, so new structure is locally `jax-files/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2` (only the files within this particular path are invoked for this example, but i imagine other resources are used in more general cases)